# Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3 Database and driver class

Tags: birt, microsoft-dynamics

I am using actuate BIRT tool and trying to make connection profile with MS dynamics AX 2012 R3, but i do not know what will be its driver class and database URL.I am not sure if MS dynamics AX 2012 R3 has MS sql server as db , but if uses MS SQL developer 2012 as its Db , then again what will be its driver class and database URl. Need your Immediate Help . Please advise and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar to BIRT. By the way, AX 2012 uses MS SQL Server as BDD. I strongly recommend to you to always connect through the AOS. Data constraints, data repartition through companies, security, etc... are handled by the AOS.

If you just need a connection string to your DB, you can find the information on the AOS box in the Server Configuration Utility on your current AOS configuration.